# PHP PREG_REPLACE changing string

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have the following String:

> "Something:string(lower-case) anything Somethingb:numbers"

I am trying to get the char after Something and the numbers after Somethingb with **preg_replace**.

Also, sometimes the string will be just the first part:

> "Something char anything"

So what I need is an outcome like this using **preg_replace**:

> "string(lowercase) , numbers"

or just

> "string(lowercase)"

if the Something b is not in the string.

Any idea would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please give more information?  I don't quite understand.  Could the 'char' be, basically, any string?  And what would be the stopping point of the match?  Can the string have spaces?  Would I want the regex to match everything up until it encountered 'Somethingb', if it existed, where it would then look for the numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is regex for first case:

```
/Something:([a-z]+).*?Somethingb:(\d+)/
```

and replace

```
$1 , $2
```

also you can pass &$count parameter to know if replace was successful

In second case do you want "Something char anything" to become "something char anything"? if this is so that you can just do strtolower($string) if $count == 0